# Redux state field depends on another field

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

In my redux state I have too fields `{a:string|undefined,prevA:string|undefined}`
I have too many `reducers` that touch the value of `a`, I would like to add the follwoing logic to my code

```
if(state.a){
   state.prevA = state.a
}
```

Which means I would like to keep the previous non-undefined value of `a` in `prevA`, But I don't like to touch to all reducers and repeat the process

How can I do it in redux? Do I have to add `middleware` ? if yes how to do it with redux-toolkit